# Python - why does eval fail on this string/expression?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, eval

I am running anaconda on OS X 10.11.5 and am struggling to access data in a pandas DataFrame. Doing it directly works fine but, when I try to evaluate arguments in a string which I have generated by iteration, it fails. Here is a simpler version that produces the same problem without the iteration.

The direct access - this works fine:

```
from pandas import *
df = read_csv('~/FutureLearn/Learn to Code for Data Analysis/WHO POP TB all.csv')

df1 = (df['Country'] == 'Brazil')    # Also works without ()
df1      # A pandas Series
df[df1]  # Accesses DataFrame OK
```

This is an attempt where the selector is generated as a string and then evaluated:

```
df1str = ("df['Country'] == 'Brazil'")
eval(df1str)   # ValueError: unknown type str224 - would have expected Series
```

This generates the ValueError and I cannot use the expression to access the DataFrame. Why doesn't this `eval` work? Or what must I do to be able to use a string to access the DataFrame?

Thanks for any help (on this, my first stackOverflow post).

Comment: `df1str = ("df['Country'] == 'Brazil'")` no output , need returned or  printed data. Eval is `string` base not `None` or `Variable` type. Python isn't magical language !

Comment: because of pandas import, isn't eval shadowed by pandas.eval?

Comment: @dsgdfg: `type(df1str)` is `str` and the variable does return the assigned string value. I assumed I could pass a variable to `eval` and `mySum = "1 + 2"; eval(mySum)` does work.

Comment: `type(df1str)` is `str` absolutely not ! You  raise a `bool` type variable not str.  `eval(str(df1str))` of course you need define  `df1str` before calling `eval` function.

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.eval](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.eval.html) **returns** the Series, so you want to use

```
lukas@crash:~/sandbox$ cat a.csv
a,b
1,2
lukas@crash:~/sandbox$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.__version__
'0.13.1'
>>> df = pandas.read_csv('a.csv')
>>> df1str = "df['a'] == '1'"
>>> df1 = pandas.eval(df1str)
>>> type(df1)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>>
```

Comment: '@luv': that sounded a promising tip (as from @joel goldstick) but when I tried `df1str = ("df['Country'] == 'Brazil'");
df1 = pandas.eval(df1str)` I still get the same **ValueError** (I presumed you meant `pandas.eval`).

Comment: I tried `pandas.eval(df1str, parser='python')` too but it still brought the same **ValueError**.

Comment: Strange. I tried it here (python 2.7.6, pandas 0.13.1) and it does work for me. I edited my answer with a full example.

Comment: '@luv': yes, Python 3.4.4, pandas 0.16.2 in my case.  (BTW why must I put quotes around @luv in Edits? The name doesn't appear otherwise.)

Comment: tried your example and it generated the same **ValueError**   `python
Python 3.4.4 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jan  9 2016, 17:30:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.read_csv('a.csv')
>>> df1str = "df['a'] == '1'"
>>> df1 = pandas.eval(df1str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/eric1/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/computation/eval.py", line 230, in eval
    truediv=truediv)`

Comment: Oh ok. I don't know how to get that working with python3, sorry.

Comment: A strange development - on further experimenting I have seen that that problem seems to depend on how you import pandas. With `import pandas`  the eval works as expected. But with `from pandas import *`eval leads to the **ValueError** problem (and that remains even if the code in the Jupyter notebook reverts to the `import pandas` version). That seems to be a bug to me but just where I cannot say.